# Writing 4 returns for one trigger, that each return is to different docRef

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to write a firestore function that onCreate of a new document
it will update couple different docs.

for example for statistics, by adding new sports session doc to sessions collection.
it will update the docs: yearlyStats, quartlyStats, monthlyStats and dailyStats.

so the question, how I write 4 returns for one trigger, that each return is to different docRef.

Do I need to write 4 separated functions with same trigger? or I can do it all in one function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are updating statistics based on new documents that are created, you may be better to use transactions. This way, you will ensure that 2 concurrent document creations don't both update the statistics documents at the same time.  You can have a transaction read the value from the new document and then update several documents.

If you simply want to write several documents at the same time, from within a Cloud Function, take a look at using Batched Writes.

The documentation for both options can be found here, [Transactions and Batched Writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions).

With both options, be aware that you can only update a single document at a rate of once per second. If you are processing large numbers of documents, then you may be better to pipe your new document data into Cloud Dataflow (via PubSub from your Cloud Function), then pass regular updates back to Cloud Firestore. If that's your use case, then this video will be useful... [Data Pipelines with Firebase and Google Cloud](https://youtu.be/guo-4IOqx2M)

### Code sample using transaction and getAll

This requires the Node SDK 0.12.0 or higher (Admin SDK >= 5.9.1)

```
const firestore = firebase.firestore();

let firstDocRef = firestore.doc('myCollection/document1');
let secondDocRef = firestore.doc('myCollection/document2');

return firestore.runTransaction(t => {
  return t.getAll(firstDocRef, secondDocRef).then(querySnapshot => {

    // Return just the data and map it to firstDoc and secondDoc (personal hack)
    querySnapshot = querySnapshot.map(doc => doc.data());
    let [firstDocData, secondDocData] = querySnapshot;

    // Increment the counters
    let firstUpdate = {myCounter: firstDocData.myCounter + 1};
    let secondUpdate = {myCounter: secondDocData.myCounter + 1};

    // Write the new data back to Cloud Firestore
    t.update(firstDocRef, firstUpdate);
    t.update(secondDocRef, secondUpdate);

  });
})
.then(() => {
  console.log('Transaction completed successfully');
})
.catch(err => {
  console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: Writing using a batch option to the documents is a good option, but as these fields are counters so before the update, I'll need to read them from the docs. Is the batch option allows it? (read couple docs and then using batch to update the docs)

Comment: You can read multiple documents in a transaction using [transaction.getAll](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.13.x/Transaction#getAll).  Once you have all of the documents, just update the documents, as required, within the transaction, before returning to the function  Theree is an error in the documentation (reported).  The array should get objects 0 and 1, not 1 and 2.

Comment: Can I use writeBatch inside the transaction? 
I'm trying it, but it returns me "Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value". if it possible then how i close this transaction function after writeBatch.commit(); command ??

Comment: I've added a code sample to my answer.  Hopefully, this should help

Comment: There was a small typo in my code that I just spotted.  If you've copied it already, please update

Comment: It works, Thanks for the code example, really helped.

Answer (score 1):

You do that by combining the promises from the four writes into a call to `Promise.all()` and returning that from your function.

Have a look at [`Promise.all()` the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), or at some of the previous [questions where `Promise.all()` was used](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bgoogle-cloud-functions%5d%20promise.all%20is%3aanswer).